# Merge the response of multiple jQuery ajax calls on a first come first served basic?

Tags: jquery, parallel-processing

I am creating a web page which issues three jQuery ajax calls in the `$(document).ready` event. And the web page merges the response of these three calls in pairs on a first come first served basic (for example, merge response 1 and  3 if they return first. Merge response 2 with any of 1 or 3 after it's returned).

How to implement it? How to avoid racing if I use a variable to store the ajax call status?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a place to store state for each response separately where all responses can see all the state (thus no race condition).  Then, at the completion of each ajax call, you check what has already completed before you.  If there's enough completed to show a response, you process that and set any new state that the remaining ajax response might need to see.  Not knowing your code structure, the easiest way to do this would be a simple array:

```
var ajaxResponses = [null, null, null];       // response values for 3 ajax calls
var ajaxProcessed = [false, false, false];    // keep track of which values have been merged
var ajaxMergeResult = null;                   // what's been merged so far
```

Then, each completion function for each ajax call can put it's response data into the array and then call a `doMerge()` function that looks at the state received so far to check if there is enough prior data for it to finish the job or do some work.  If it does some work, but all calls aren't done yet, it must store what is had done so that the next call to `doMerge()` when the last one finishes knows what has been done so far and it will only need to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is no racing in JavaScript, as JavaScript is not parallel. When it comes to HTTP requests it's *asynchronous*, which is something entirely different.

*First come, first serve* is as straight-forward as it gets:

```
var responses = [];
var urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];

for (var i=0, j=urls.length; i<j; i++) {
  $.ajax({ 
    url: urls[i],
    success: function (data) {
      responses.push(data);
    }
  });
}
```

done.